# Where is the detailed description of the esds box of the mp4 file

Tags: mp4, aac, fmp4

In which document does the esds box of mp4 file have a detailed description? Why is it not found in the ISO/ IEC 14496-12 document

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s not found in 14496-12 because it’s documented in 14496-1

Comment: Well, does it charge?Because I did not find it in the following webpage(ISO Publicly Available Standards)

https://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/index.html

Comment: Yes, I believe it is not a publicly available document.